# Where will i write require params in rails 3.2.13?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Todoscontroller.rb**

```
    class TodosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    @project = Project.new
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @todos }

    end
  end

  # GET /todos/1
  # GET /todos/1.json
  def show
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @todo }
    end
  end

  # GET /todos/new
  # GET /todos/new.json
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @todo }
    end
  end

  # GET /todos/1/edit
  def edit
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /todos
  # POST /todos.json
  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@todo, :notice => 'Todo was successfully created.') }
        format.json  { render :json => @todo, :status => :created, :location => @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json  { render :json => @todo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /todos/1
  # PUT /todos/1.json
  def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.update_attributes(params[:todo])
        format.html { redirect_to(@todo, :notice => 'Todo was successfully updated.') }
        format.json  { render :json => {} }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json  { render :json => @todo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todos/1
  # DELETE /todos/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @todo.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(todos_url) }
      format.json  { render :json => {} }
    end
  end
  def newproject
       @projects = Project.all       
    end

end
```

**Todos.rb**

```
 class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :order
      t.boolean :done

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :todos
  end
end
```

**migration file.rb**

```
class AddColumnToTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :todos, :project_id, :integer
  end
   def self.down
    add_column :todos, :project_id
  end
end
```

**todo.rb**

```
    class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :content, :presence => true
  attr_accessible :content, :order, :done, :project_id
  belongs_to :project  
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :todos
end
```

Here i created new field ("project_id") for Todo model. Here my problem project_id is not saved in Database. Where will i write require params in Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Can you give me the content of your Todo.rb model ?

Comment: You have to add association to store the project_id automatically. Dont have to explicitly save the project id. You can just go through the link once http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/association_basics.html

Comment: ya i added please check it out

Comment: ya ok, but in my database project_id field stored has null, so that's why doesn't occur associations. Prosenjit Saha

Comment: Have you added the `has_many :todos` in your Project model (`project.rb`)

Comment: ya i added in project.rb

Comment: Ok perfect, now, can you write this `raise @todo.inspect` line 47 (after `@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])`) and try to save again ? Rails will show you the content of your `@todo` object, and you'll say me if there is a nil project_id

Comment: 45
app_view.js?1437046358:55 Object {content: "9", order: 9, done: false, pid: "45"}

Comment: @Kiran Can you please push your changes to github and share the url here.

Comment: Nop, raise in this file `todoscontroller.rb`

Comment: why are  you raising the exception?

Comment: dw @ProsenjitSaha i just want to see if the object is instanced with a nil `project_id`

Comment: She has written the wrong code. She is not using the association to create the todo although she has added the `has_many: todos` association in the project model. what is necessary here to check if the object is instanced with a nil project id?

Comment: Ok How to show project_id params in todscontroller.rb

Answer (score 0):

Todo form should look like:

```
<%= form_for @todo, url: project_todos_path(@project), method: :post do |f| %>
 ......
 ......
<% end %>
```

And the todos_controller code:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project])
  @todo = @project.todos.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @todo = @project.todos.create(params[:todo])
end
```

Just do like above. It will fix your problem

Comment: Just add how he should write is `routes.rb` with nested resources and this answer will deserve a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

params require you can define in method for example in Todoscontroller.rb you can give like this

```
def todo_params
params.require(:todo).permit(
:order,
:project_id
end


def create
@todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @todo.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@todo, :notice => 'Todo was successfully created.') }
    format.json  { render :json => @todo, :status => :created, :location => @todo }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json  { render :json => @todo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```